# About robocopy slient operation result

Tags: windows, robocopy

I want to use robocopy to mirror a one way backup(mirroring) a directory, there are a lots of file list out what it is copying and flushing the screen all the time, so I search on Internet to how to make robocopy to do in slient mode then found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898127/how-can-i-make-robocopy-silent-in-the-command-line-except-for-progress).

I don't want to list out the file being copying BUT I still want the job header and job summary, so I didn't put `/NJH` and `/NJS` parameter, and put all the other parameter suggested by "R. Koene" on the above thread, the final command shown as below (I have mis-entered `NP` and `NFL` twice but it should not affect the result):

`robocopy \\192.168.1.1\Backup\ C:\Backup /MIR /ETA /mt:120 /r:10 /w:10 /FFT /np /nfl /NS /NC /NFL /NP  /xa:sh /xf *.bak Thumbs.db *.torrent ._.DS_Store .DS_Store .picasa.ini`

However, after the file processing, I see there are some of the file still listing out, but what is the status of those file or directory?, is it deleted? copied from source?  or locked so cannot copy?

For sure I can check it one by one, but it is quite frustrating when the list is long, and the main point is it is supposed to be silent operation.

[image]

Comment: Maybe add in at the end. `.ini .docx .pdf .exe .zip .txt`  From my understanding of looking at your script.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin For my script, it is intented to exclude some temp file extension and common cache file, I dont want to exclude `.ini .docx .pdf .exe .zip .txt`, which is usually are useful data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a freeware called FastCopy(http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) to solve my problem.

To exclude some type of file using FastCopy, it use exclude filter format by using semi colon like `*.bak;Thumbs.db;*.torrent;._.DS_Store;.DS_Store;.picasa.ini`

For the one way mirroring feature(equivalent of `/MIR`), use`sync` parameter

`/FFT` is not required in fastcopy